# how to use ajax to upload file image?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am usin Laravel Framework.

I have to use Ajax to upload file image but it response `Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on null`.

**Form**

```
<form action="{{ route('agent.hotel.image.gallery') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="form_upload">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="file" name="image_gallery" id="image"> 
</form>
```

**Script**

```
$("#image").on('change', function () {
var image = $(this).val();
  $.ajax({
   method: 'POST',
   url: '{{ route('agent.hotel.image.gallery') }}',
   data: { image_gallery: image, '_token': '{{ csrf_token() }}' },
   success: function (data) {
   console.log(data);
   }
  });
});
```

**Controller**

```
// Image Gallery

$image = $request->file('image_gallery');
$filename = md5(time()) . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
$save = public_path('/hotel_picture/' . $filename);

//Move file upload to public folder
Image::make($image)->save($save);
```

Anyone can help ? or Have other method to do this ?

Comment: `.val()` returns the fake path of the file, not the `File` object, you can get the `File` object using the `.files` property of `<input type="file">` element. Your server appears to expect key, value pair of `"image_gallery"`, `File` object

Comment: You may have to use `FormData()` to pass an image via ajax

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To `POST` `File` object you can use `FormData()` with key, value pairs matching key that server is expecting. Set `processData` and `contentType` of `$.ajax()` settings to `false`

```
$("#image").on('change', function () {
  var image = this.files[0];
  var fd = new FormData();
  fd.append("image_gallery", image);
  fd.append("_token", "{{ csrf_token() }}");
  $.ajax({
   method: 'POST',
   url: "{{ route('agent.hotel.image.gallery') }}",
   data: fd,
   processData: false,
   contentType: false,
   success: function (data) {
     console.log(data);
   }
  });
});
```

Comment: @Chando, If that code works then you should accept the answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to directly submit a form like so :

```
 $("#image").on('change', function () {
      $(this).parents("form").submit():
    });
```

Comment: form submit it redirect to other route. I want to upload image without reload page.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
$("#image").on('change', function () {
    $("#form_upload").submit();
});

$("#form_upload").on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
    formData.append('image_gallery', $('#image')[0].files[0]);
    formData.append("_token", "{{ csrf_token() }}");
    $.ajax({
        url: '{{ route('agent.hotel.image.gallery') }}',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data)
        },
        cache: false,
        processData: false
    });
    return false;
});
```